# Adding an entity in an other bundle through forms symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I wanted to ask about adding an entity in one bundle through a form of an entity in an other different bundle.

I feel this is impossible in symfony because when I tried it, I got a warning.

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to xxx\twoBundle\Entity\entity1::setUser() must be an instance of xxx\oneBundle\Entity\User, array given, called in C:\wamp\www\Symfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\Util\PropertyPath.php on line 538 and defined in C:\wamp\www\Symfony\src\xxx\twoBundle\Entity\entity1.php line 446
```

Any ideas???

Answer (score 0):

Ok create a form type for your entity and set the dataClass:

```
class MySecondEntityFormType {

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{        
    $builder->add('someField');
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'XXX\TwoBundle\Entity\MySecondEntity',
    ));
}
```

Now in the main form add the newly created form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{        
    ...
    $builder->add('mySecondEntity', new MySecondEntityFormType());
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'compound' => true
    ));
}
```

Comment: actually I want to add a new entry and not retrieve data from the database. That's why I used $builder->add('user', new UserType()); but this doesn't resolve the problem. @Thomas K

Comment: but when using your suggestion, it worked and everything is ok in the database. @Thomas K

Comment: I dont't fully understand? Did my solution solve your problem?

Comment: it's working. but this is not what I need. I want to add entry and not to get them from the database. @Thomas K

Comment: The form's view data is expected to be of type scalar, array or an instance of \ArrayAccess, but is an instance of class Proxies\__CG__\xxx\UserBundle\Entity\User. You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to "Proxies\__CG__\xxx\UserBundle\Entity\User" or by adding a view transformer that transforms an instance of class Proxies\__CG__\xxx\UserBundle\Entity\User to scalar, array or an instance of \ArrayAccess.  => Now I get the following warrning. @Thomas K

Comment: OK so set the data_class option on the main form to something like  `XXX\TwoBundle\Entity\MyFirstEntity`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29320/discussion-between-user2269869-and-thomas-k)